# WPF приложение в Visual Studio 2010 только для С# и VB или для С++ тоже возможно?

Tags: wpf, .net, visual-studio

Просто недавно начал изучать **Visual Studio** и писал проект **Windows Form** на **С++/CLI**, потом случайно наткнулся на **WPF**, понравилось и совсем не глючит, как конструктор **Windows Form**, только вот в установленных шаблонах - **приложение WPF**, есть только для **С#** и **VB**, а для **С++** только **Windows Form, CLR, MFC** и т.д.

Вот и возник вопрос есть ли вобще такая возможность?

*(извините если вопрос ламерский, я еще просто многого не понимаю).*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Выбор между Presentation Foundation и Forms практически всегда решается в пользу первого: оно является развитием (наследником и заменой) второго. Если нет каких-либо серьезных причин использовать Windows Forms: большой унаследованный код, уже приобретенные дорогие платные компоненты, незнакомство коллектива разработчиков с WPF, то выбор - в пользу WPF.

Можно ли писать приложения WPF на управляемом C++? Можно. Пример:

```
#include <windows.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows;

[STAThread]
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE instance, HINSTANCE previousInstance, LPSTR commandLine, int commandShow)
{
    Window^ w = gcnew Window();
    w->Title = "Hello World";

    Application^ a = gcnew Application();
    a->Run(w);
}
```

Нужно собрать этот код с ключом /clr, добавив ссылки на сборки windowsbase.dll, presentationcore.dll и presentationframeworkd.dll, и вы получите простейшее приложение WPF. Вообще можно писать WPF-приложения с помощью разных языков, в том числе IronPython или IronRuby.

Стоит ли писать на управляемом C++ под WPF? Нет. Написание кода на C# гораздо проще, удобней и легче. Поэтому из шаблонов и убраны варианты на C++.